# how to play mp3 file after downloaded using ngcordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making a cordova app to download mp3 file from server then store into the phone and then user can play it locally.

my code to download mp3 file looks like this

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(Filename){
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://archive.org/download/Kansas_Joe_Memphis_Minnie-When_Levee_Breaks/Kansas_Joe_and_Memphis_Minnie-When_the_Levee_Breaks.mp3");
        var downloadPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory+'download.mp3';

        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            downloadPath,
            function(entry) {
                $scope.savepath = entry.toURL();
                alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("download error");
            },
            false,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
            }
        );
    }//End DownloadFile
```

I download mp3 file from server and store it in iPhone by name download.mp3. when I would like to play it I use the file path `cordova.file.dataDirectory+'download.mp3'` but there is an error, it like the app couldn't find the `download.mp3`

this is the log from xCode

```
Unknown resource 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F4G316AE-5BB2-3F1A-A65B-A84E3F7152AC/Library/NoCloud/download.mp3'
```

I would like to ask you guys if there are any way to check the correct file path or any idea of solve this problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

You need to take off the "file://" from the file path

```
fileURL = fileURL.replace('file://','');

$scope.media = new Media(fileURL);

$cordovaMedia.play($scope.media);

/*
'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXXX/Library/NoCloud/download.mp3'
--> Unknown resource

'/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXXX/Library/NoCloud/download.mp3'
--> play ok!
*/
```